# Replaying flow from last checkpoint error

Tags: corda

Please note that my node is part of **Corda TestNet** and it's deployed on Google Cloud Platform.
I'm using the following:
1. Corda OS 4.1 (updated to `4.3-RC01`)
2. Tokens SDK 1.1-SNAPSHOT (updated to `1.1-RC01`)
3. `OKHttp 3.5.0`

I have a flow that does the following:
 1. Make an HTTP call (using OKHttp as per the HTTP example from the Samples repo); during my local tests I got an error that the `Client`, `Request`, and `Response` objects cannot be serialized so I nullified those references and it worked.
 2. Fetch the latest version of my `EvolvableTokenType`
 3. Use that version to create new `FungibleTokens`
 4. Call `IssueTokens` sub-flow
 5. Sleep for one millisecond (to checkpoint the flow); I removed this and still got the same error.
 6. Call `UpdateEvolvableToken` sub-flow (my token-type has a field that tracks the number of issued tokens, so after each issue; I update that field).

This all works when I run my flow tests or when I run the flow locally from the node terminal (against H2 and Postgres DB).

I deployed this CorDapp to GCP (Google Cloud Platfrom) and I was able to run a different flow from that app, but when I run this flow; I get the below error:

```
net.corda.node.services.statemachine.FlowTimeoutException: replaying flow from the last checkpoint
    at net.corda.node.services.statemachine.SingleThreadedStateMachineManager$scheduleTimeoutException$$inlined$with$lambda$1.run(SingleThreadedStateMachineManager.kt:638) ~[corda-node-4.1.jar:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_222]
```

I removed the HTTP call (fearing it was the issue) and redeployed, re-ran on GCP and I still got that error.

Comment: I opened an issue for this error on Corda's repo (as per Roger's direction).

Comment: Most up to date info is in the following issue: https://github.com/corda/corda/issues/5593

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but for a start Tokens 1.1 should be using Corda 4.3 :)

Comment: I'll give it a try Roger.

Comment: I'm unable to add the new `selection` module dependency; could not find `com.r3.corda.lib.tokens:tokens-selection:1.1-RC01`

Comment: I get this when I try to run my flow tests (after adding **TestCordapp.findCordapp("com.r3.corda.lib.tokens.selection")**). ```java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: There are no CorDapps containing the package com.r3.corda.lib.tokens.selection on the classpath. Make sure the package name is correct and that the CorDapp is added as a gradle dependency.```

Comment: Sorry - it has been published now. https://ci-artifactory.corda.r3cev.com/artifactory/corda-lib-dev/com/r3/corda/lib/tokens/token-selection/1.1-RC01/

Comment: Renamed the dependency from `token-selection` to `tokens-selection` as it should be: https://ci-artifactory.corda.r3cev.com/artifactory/corda-lib-dev/com/r3/corda/lib/tokens/tokens-selection/1.1-RC01/

Comment: Upgrading to `Corda OS 4.3-RC01` and `Tokens 1.1-RC01` as proposed, didn't resolve the issue.